# EmailMessage before insert trigger not working as expected?

Tags: apex, trigger, email, order-of-execution

I have a before insert trigger on `EmailMessage` object and here is the trigger:

It just adds some extra content to the end of the email content.

```
trigger EmailMessageTrigger on EmailMessage (before insert) {
    if (trigger.isBefore && trigger.insert){
        for (EmailMessage eMsg: newList){
            eMsg.TextBody = eMsg.TextBody + '\n \n ******************* : ';
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how it looks in salesforce when I send email by clicking on the 'send Email' button:

[image]

but the actual email sent out doesn't have the extra content that I added in the trigger:

Below is the screenshot of the 'Show original' in my gmail:

[image]

What am I missing here?

How come in salesforce it shows that the email sent out has the extra characters appended in the trigger but the actual email received doesn't have that content?

Is it because of the order of execution??

Comment: Why is this downvoted??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The content of the email sent out to the recipient can't be changed by changing the content in EmailMessage record. When you do the change in before insert, it modifies only the EmailMessage record and the original message sent out is not altered.

For the inbound message, the content customer sent will be received as is to our outlook/gmail inbox. But the EmailMessage record can be altered to store additional characters in it body.

If you really want to change the content, add a template or modify the body before sending out the email.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this to say that the EmailMessage record does NOT finish it's beforeInsert/Update triggers before sending the email?

Comment: the above is true also for the `EmailMessage.Subject`